# How can I create conditional column for two sets in a window of a key?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two tables with information on retailers users used in pre- and post-periods. My goal is to find what retailers were new for users in postperiod. I wonder how to do it in a `user_id` window, because `is_in()` and `loc[]` solutions do not fit well for my task. Also I was thinking about filtering joins (anti-join specifically) but it did not work well. Here's sample data:

```
sample1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'user_id': [45, 556, 556, 556, 556, 556, 556, 1344, 1588, 2063, 2063, 2063, 2673, 2982, 2982],
        'retailer': ['retailer_1', 'retailer_1', 'retailer_2', 'retailer_3', 'retailer_4', 'retailer_5', 'retailer_6', 
                     'retailer_3', 'retailer_2', 'retailer_2', 'retailer_3', 'retailer_7', 'retailer_1', 'retailer_1', 'retailer_2']
    }
)

sample2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'user_id': [45, 45, 556, 556, 556, 556, 556, 556, 1344, 1588, 2063, 2063, 2063, 2673, 2673, 2982, 2982],
        'retailer': ['retailer_1', 'retailer_6', 'retailer_1', 'retailer_2', 'retailer_3', 'retailer_4', 'retailer_5', 'retailer_6', 
                     'retailer_3', 'retailer_2', 'retailer_2', 'retailer_3', 'retailer_7', 'retailer_1', 'retailer_2', 'retailer_1', 'retailer_2']
    }
)
```

My desired result is like this:

```
{'user_id': {0: 45, 1: 45, 2: 556, 3: 556, 4: 556, 5: 556, 6: 556, 7: 556, 8: 1344, 9: 1588, 10: 2063, 11: 2063, 12: 2063, 13: 2673, 14: 2673, 15: 2982, 16: 2982}, 'retailer': {0: 'retailer_1', 1: 'retailer_6', 2: 'retailer_1', 3: 'retailer_2', 4: 'retailer_3', 5: 'retailer_4', 6: 'retailer_5', 7: 'retailer_6', 8: 'retailer_3', 9: 'retailer_2', 10: 'retailer_2', 11: 'retailer_3', 12: 'retailer_7', 13: 'retailer_1', 14: 'retailer_2', 15: 'retailer_1', 16: 'retailer_2'}, 'is_new_retailer': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 12: 0, 13: 0, 14: 1, 15: 0, 16: 0}}
```

Comment: desired solution can be parsed using ```pd.DataFrame.from_dict()``` function if it seems confusing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea is use `indicator` parameter in left join, so is possible identify row from left side, working perfect if no duplicates by both columns in both DataFrames.

```
out = sample2.merge(sample1, indicator='is_new_retailer', how='left')
out['is_new_retailer'] = out['is_new_retailer'].eq('left_only').astype(int)
print (out)
    user_id    retailer  is_new_retailer
0        45  retailer_1                0
1        45  retailer_6                1
2       556  retailer_1                0
3       556  retailer_2                0
4       556  retailer_3                0
5       556  retailer_4                0
6       556  retailer_5                0
7       556  retailer_6                0
8      1344  retailer_3                0
9      1588  retailer_2                0
10     2063  retailer_2                0
11     2063  retailer_3                0
12     2063  retailer_7                0
13     2673  retailer_1                0
14     2673  retailer_2                1
15     2982  retailer_1                0
16     2982  retailer_2                0
```

General solution is test `MultiIndex`es by [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
mux1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(sample2[['user_id','retailer']])
mux2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(sample1[['user_id','retailer']])
sample2['is_new_retailer'] = (~mux1.isin(mux2).astype(int)
print (sample2)
    user_id    retailer  is_new_retailer
0        45  retailer_1                0
1        45  retailer_6                1
2       556  retailer_1                0
3       556  retailer_2                0
4       556  retailer_3                0
5       556  retailer_4                0
6       556  retailer_5                0
7       556  retailer_6                0
8      1344  retailer_3                0
9      1588  retailer_2                0
10     2063  retailer_2                0
11     2063  retailer_3                0
12     2063  retailer_7                0
13     2673  retailer_1                0
14     2673  retailer_2                1
15     2982  retailer_1                0
16     2982  retailer_2                0
```

Comment: wow, did not know about ```indicator``` argument. it shows from which table a row appeared?

Comment: it is very strange but I cannot reproduce your solution. In the column ```is_new_retailer``` I receive ```both``` condition for user_id 45. What can be a possible reason for this?

Comment: @rg4s In data from question?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your solution on actual data that I am working with but I built sample datasets very similar to actual data

Comment: And if I specify a column to join on on a sample data, it does not differentiate between left-only and right-only

Comment: @rg4s - hmmm, I use no parameter `on`, so it means joined by both columns.

Comment: Oh, yeas, I see. Thank you!